# Javascript: passing large data sets to multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, widget, yui3

I'm using YUI3 widgets, but for you jquery guys just pretend we are talking about plugins.  I have a large json data set with over 5,000 records in it.  In my applications I have at least 5 widgets that need access to my data set.  Currently I'm embedding the json in the html and grabbing it with YUI3 on page load, before I render my widgets.

What I want to avoid is having 5 copies of my data set stored in memory.  I'm trying to come up with a design pattern that allows me to avoid this.  I believe if I pass this data in as an attribute to my widget, it will pass it by value, not reference and essentially copy it in memory ... let me know if I am wrong about this.  Since the data is globally available, my widgets can access it directly, but I think this will also copy the data in memory.

I think if I initially create an object, loading my data in the object and pass that object in as an attribute it will pass it by reference, which will allow all of my widgets to access the same instance of my data.

Is this what you would do?  Please let me know you thoughts and how you would set something like this up.

Thanks for your (positive) input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the "data set" around in a separate .js file of its own, defined like this:

```
// My Huge Data Set
// Author: bababa
//
(function(window) {
  window['hugeDataSet'] = {
    // millions of lines of stuff
  };
})(this);
```

then when you import that with a plain `<script>` tag or with a script loader, there'll just be one global copy of the data.  You can reference it like this:

```
someWidget.doSomething(hugeDataSet);
```

and that will not make a copy of the data. Of course, you can drop the data inline, in a `<script>` in your HTML, but then it won't be cached if your HTML is generated by a server-side template (like php or jsp or whatever).

Comment: The html isn't dynamic, but the data is. I am currently embedding it in the html with a script tag, so I do currently have global access to the data set from all of my widgets.  So, every time I assign my data to a variable in one of my widgets it doesn't make a copy in memory?  I'm not totally sure how JS handles things like this. Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: No, simply passing a reference to an object definitely does not make a copy. You have to really write code explicitly to make copies, in fact.

Answer (score -1):

Do your widget need to access all 5,000 records each time? Or do they only require a specific subset of your data?

It seems to me that you are trying to use json has an alternative for a database here.

The most likely solution is to put your data in a proper database, request the data you need with a server-side script and json these data back to your widget.

Parsing text is very slow compared to a database query.

Comment: The data is in a databse and we are not using json to replace it.  We are making a single application that handles almost everything on the client side.  We want it to be really quick and not hitting the server every time we do something simple like request a new page, which is why we are doing this way.

Comment: Dumping the content of the database in JSON and sending it to the client *is* replacing the DB with json. Loading 5K records and parsing it in JavaScript is not the fastest way to go (or else, you wouldn't be asking this question. As Pointy noted your dataset is not getting copied several times over). Consider a mix of caching and prefetch to optimize the speed.